# Nested loop over combination

Tags: python, loops, iterator, combinations

Iterating over combinations doesn't give the expected number of iterations. To illustrate my problem:

```
import itertools

combinations = itertools.combinations(range(10), 1) # The combination has 10 elements

# Test1
count = 0
for c1 in combinations:
    for c2 in combinations:
        count += 1
print("Test1:", count)

# Test2
combinations1 = itertools.combinations(range(10), 1)
combinations2 = itertools.combinations(range(10), 1)

count = 0
for c1 in combinations1:
    for c2 in combinations2:
        count += 1
print("Test2:", count)

# Test3
combinations1 = list(itertools.combinations(range(10), 1))
combinations2 = list(itertools.combinations(range(10), 1))

count = 0
for c1 in combinations1:
    for c2 in combinations2:
        count += 1
print("Test3:", count)
```

I'm iterating over a combination of 10 elements. With a double nested loop, I would expect 100 iterations (10x10). However, I get the following results:

```
Test1: 9
Test2: 10
Test3: 100
```

I can understand that `Test1` does not work correctly, since I'm using the same object for both loops. However, I would expect both `Test2` and `Test3` to yield the same results since the only difference is that I converted the iterator objects to lists first in `Test3`.

I would really appreciate any explanations regarding this issue. I'm using Python 3.8.2 with Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, you can only iterate `combinations2` once. This can be demonstrated by adding some `print`s in:

```
count = 0
for c1 in combinations1:
    print("Outer")
    for c2 in combinations2:
        print("inner")
        count += 1
print("Test2:", count)

Outer
inner
inner
inner
inner
inner
inner
inner
inner
inner
inner
Outer
Outer  <-- Noteworthy
Outer
Outer
Outer
Outer
Outer
Outer
Outer
Test2: 10
```

`combinations` returns an iterator, and an iterator can only be iterated once. If you try to call `next` on it after it's exhausted, it'll still be exhausted.

Your third example works because it's lists that are being iterated. When you iterate a list, `iter(a_list)` is implicitly called, which creates a new iterator each time. Contrast that with `iter(an_iterator)` that evaluates to itself; not a new iterator.